# Avoid AWK printing an initial empty line

Tags: printing, awk

I am pretty sure this is straightforward but I haven't found a question related to this issue.
I am using the next code to print the first start site and the final end site for a given gene in the 5th column of `PosGen.bed`

```
awk 'BEGIN{ch=$1;ini=$2;fin=$3;gen=$5}{if(gen==$5){fin=$3}else{print ch"\t"ini"\t"fin"\t"gen;ch=$1;ini=$2;fin=$3;gen=$5}}}END{print ch"\t"ini"\t"fin"\t"gen}' PosGen.bed | head
```

What I did was to keep the very first site >BEGIN<. Then, the conditional `if` will verify if the next line, or even the  first line, has the same gene name, if so, the end site is refreshed with the new end site.
If detects other gene name, it will print out all the actual info and replace it with that of the new gene. My code works as expected, but I can't get rid of that initial line; this can be easily removed from the output file, but am eager to learn and eventually master `awk`...

So, the question is: **My code is printing an initial empty line, and I haven't detected the reason, Do you know why am printing an empty line?**

I though this was because of misplaced {braquets} but this doesn't appear to be the problem.
Here is an example of the output I'm getting and the input.

*Any help will be highly appreciated!
Thank you!*

### Output File (with our friend the empty line)

```
chr1    3204563 3661429 Xkr4
chr1    4280927 4399268 Rp1
chr1    4481009 4486494 Sox17
chr1    4763279 4775758 Mrpl15
```

### Input File

```
chr1 3204563 3207049 - Xkr4
chr1 3206103 3206105 - Xkr4
chr1 3206106 3207049 - Xkr4
chr1 3411783 3411982 - Xkr4
chr1 3411783 3411982 - Xkr4
chr1 3660633 3661429 - Xkr4
chr1 3660633 3661579 - Xkr4
chr1 3661427 3661429 - Xkr4
chr1 4280927 4283093 - Rp1
chr1 4283062 4283064 - Rp1
chr1 4283065 4283093 - Rp1
chr1 4333588 4340172 - Rp1
chr1 4334681 4334683 - Rp1
chr1 4334684 4340172 - Rp1
chr1 4341991 4342162 - Rp1
chr1 4341991 4342162 - Rp1
chr1 4341991 4342162 - Rp1
chr1 4341991 4342162 - Rp1
chr1 4342283 4342906 - Rp1
chr1 4342283 4342918 - Rp1
chr1 4342283 4342918 - Rp1
chr1 4342283 4342918 - Rp1
chr1 4342904 4342906 - Rp1
chr1 4350281 4350395 - Rp1
chr1 4399251 4399268 - Rp1
chr1 4399251 4399322 - Rp1
chr1 4399266 4399268 - Rp1
chr1 4481009 4482749 - Sox17
chr1 4481797 4481799 - Sox17
chr1 4481800 4482749 - Sox17
chr1 4483181 4483487 - Sox17
chr1 4483181 4483547 - Sox17
chr1 4483485 4483487 - Sox17
chr1 4483853 4483944 - Sox17
chr1 4485217 4486023 - Sox17
chr1 4486372 4486494 - Sox17
chr1 4763279 4764597 - Mrpl15
```

Comment: White space is surprisingly inexpensive, it's always wise to invest in some when writing code. Brevity is not a desirable attribute of software - conciseness is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `}` before `END` that makes you code fail (give error), remove it.

The `BEGIN` section does not do anything, since `$1,$2 etc` do not contain nothing before first line is run.

Rewriting your code some, makes it more easy to read.
Since `gen` does not contain anything in first run, you `if` goes to the `else` section.
The first thing it does there is to print `ini` `fin` and  `gen`.  And on first run this does not contain anything, give blank line (wrong use of `BEGIN`)

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    ch=$1
    ini=$2
    fin=$3
    gen=$5
}
{
    if (gen==$5) {
        fin=$3
    }
    else {
        print ch"\t"ini"\t"fin"\t"gen
        ch=$1
        ini=$2
        fin=$3
        gen=$5
    }
}
END {
    print ch"\t"ini"\t"fin"\t"gen
}
' file
```

PS When posting here select code and click `{}` to outline code.

---

So to solve this, change  `BEGIN` to `NR==1` to make it run for first line like this:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
NR==1 {
    ch=$1
    ini=$2
    fin=$3
    gen=$5
}
{
    if (gen==$5) {
        fin=$3
    }
    else {
        print ch, ini, fin, gen
        ch=$1
        ini=$2
        fin=$3
        gen=$5
    }
}
END {
    print ch, ini, fin, gen
}
' file
chr1    3204563 3661429 Xkr4
chr1    4280927 4399268 Rp1
chr1    4481009 4486494 Sox17
chr1    4763279 4764597 Mrpl15
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!
Indeed I misunderstood the use of `BEGIN`

Answer (score 2):

As @Jotne points out, you misunderstand the use of `BEGIN` - it is executed before the first input file is opened for reading and so `$0`, `$1`, etc. ar not populated in that section. Try this instead:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ OFS="\t" }
{
    if ($5 == gen) {
        fin = $3
    }
    else {
        prtGen()
        ch  = $1
        ini = $2
        gen = $5
    }
}
END { prtGen() }

function prtGen() {
    if (ini != "") {
        print ch, ini, fin, gen
    }
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
chr1    3204563 3661429 Xkr4
chr1    4280927 4399268 Rp1
chr1    4481009 4486494 Sox17
chr1    4763279 4764597 Mrpl15
```

Note that the above will not produce any output if the input file is empty which is something you always want from a text processing script.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the question of the starting empty line, but this alternative approach may be interesting in this case, if the input file is ordered:

```
awk '$NF!=p{print x}{p=$NF}1' file | awk '{print $1,$2,$(NF-2),$NF}' RS=
```

Output:

```
chr1 3204563 3661429 Xkr4
chr1 4280927 4399268 Rp1
chr1 4481009 4486494 Sox17
chr1 4763279 4764597 Mrpl15
```